# Modifying a matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I have a matrix equation of the form

$$
Q=SBS+SBA+HSBZ+ABS+ABA+ABZ+ZBS+ZBA+ZBZ.
$$

If it weren't for the $H$ matrix in the third term, the whole thing would be

$$
Q^\prime=(S+A+Z)B(S+A+Z).
$$

As it is, I was able to reduce it to

$$
Q=(S+A+Z)B(S+A+Z)+(H-I)SBZ,
$$
but I want to eliminate the addition, if possible. In other words, I am looking for an expression like

$$
Q=f(S,A,H,Z)Bg(S,A,H,Z),
$$
where $f(.)$ and $g(.)$ are matrix functions.

All matrices are square and real. $S$ is symmetric and $H$ is a diagonal.

I am looking for some $f(.)$ and $g(.)$. I will be calculating
$$
Q^{(n)}=f^n(S,A,H,Z) B g^n(S,A,H,Z),
$$
and I will be using SVD to proceed. Thus eliminating the addition helps me a lot.

Thanks!

Comment: A symmetric and a diagonal matrix do not commute in general. Can you check if in your case they really commute?

Comment: @PC1 They do not. I thought they always commuted. I am now removing the commutation part. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is a way to write what you're trying to do in a straightforward manner. In any case, what are the unknowns in your equation? For instance, if you try to find $B$ then you have likely a Lyupanov discrete equation.

Comment: @PC1 Thanks! I will check the Lyupanov equation. But I am not solving for $B$. I start with $B$ and iterate it $n$ times. This is the matrix representation of Brownian Motion. It shifts the $B$ Matrix up and down, left and right. Thus all elements of all these matrices are either 0 or 1.